# When I open an image from Unity in preview it's blank?

Tags: unity, textures, image

Ok, I need to know why this is and don't have the .png anywhere else. I have a texture in Unity that I need to edit in Photoshop, yet when I Reveal the image in Finder then open it in preview or photoshop, the whole thing is blank.

It is clearly not a blank image, and other images are not doing this:

[image]

What is wrong here?

Comment: Is your alpha channel all zero (or close to it)?

Comment: shouldn't be.. it's just a diffuse texture exported from substance. Where would I change/check that?

Comment: If Substance is using the alpha channel for something like roughness/smoothness/metalness, and your material is matte dielectric, then it wouldn't be unusual to get an all-0 alpha channel. Usually I try to save images as TGA format if the alpha channel does not represent transparency, to maintain the independence of the colour & alpha. I don't know if there are utilities to separate/discard alpha from a png while preserving the colour... we might be able to do it via a Unity script if other workflows don't present themselves.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for that - basically I deleted the substance project and am trying to work w just this png

Answer (score 1):

Open photoshop and do layer mask from transparency, then disable the mask.